# How do I deploy WebApp into existing Vnet and Subnet in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

We have our own Virtual Network. Now we want to deploy WebApp into an existing Virtual Network. Looking for the available options in Azure, is there any ARM template available?
One option I found - [App Service Environment V2](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Azure/Azure-Application-Service-Environments-v2-Private-PaaS-Environments-in-the-Cloud?term=app%20service%20environment)

Please help me for other options and ARM template to create the Infrastructure and WebbApp.

Thanks.

Regards,
Deb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Azure App Service Environment is a deployment of Azure App Service into a subnet in an Azure virtual network (VNet).

Take a look at this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-external-ase

Create ASE from template
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-from-template

Template example on github samples
https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/templates/201-web-app-asev2-create

Comment: Thanks. ASE is approx ~1000 USD/Month, is there any other option.

Comment: Nope. I am not aware of other options

Comment: @DebasisGhosh if you have the answer you wanted then could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Its not an answer to my question, looking for something else already mention. Thanks. Deb

Answer (score 2):

[App Service Environment](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Azure/Azure-Application-Service-Environments-v2-Private-PaaS-Environments-in-the-Cloud?term=app%20service%20environment) is the only option to deploy Azure Web App into existing VNet/Subnet (Private).

Answer (score 0):

If you created your resources manually you can download your ARM template from Azure. Just click your resource group and then "Automation script". You can download it and use with PowerShell to deploy everything:

[image]